# Selecting column names separated by a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL statement (SQL Server) which selects column names under specific conditions and "returns" all column names separated by a `,`.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE OWNER = 'KOCH' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1';
```

This returns several rows of column names:

```
NAME
ID
STATE
CITY
```

But I want them to be returned in this format:

```
NAME, ID, STATE, CITY
```

(I think I have to use `FROM dual`)?

Comment: Even though you keep repeating that you are using SQL Server, the fact that you are using `all_tab_columns` and talk about `dual` points to you actually using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:

```
;WITH CTE_Columns (column_list, column_id) AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(500)) AS column_list,
        COLUMN_ID
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS C
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1' AND
        COLUMN_ID= 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(column_list + ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(500)),
        C.COLUMN_ID
    FROM
        CTE_Columns CL
    INNER JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS C ON
        C.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1' AND
        C.COLUMN_ID = CL.COLUMN_ID + 1
)
SELECT column_list
FROM CTE_Columns
WHERE
    COLUMN_ID =
          (
              SELECT MAX(COLUMN_ID)
              FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1')
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I am using Oracle and SQL Developer.
The table INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't exist but I can use USER_TAB_COLUMNS to get the column names.
But when I tested it said:
ORA-00904: "ORDINAL_POSITION": invalid identifier

Comment: `ORDINAL_POSITION` is a column that's in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, so if you're not using that then of course it won't exist. In `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` (and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` you should be able to use `column_id`

Comment: Ah ok thanks, he also doesn't know CTE_COLUMNS, I suppose.
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Do you know what I have to use there?

Comment: CTE_Columns is just an alias that I've given to the CTE. Oracle might not need the preceding semi-colon before the `WITH`, but otherwise I don't know what the issue might be.